# Como puedo implementar la matSort en Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

Tengo mi component.html de la siguiente forma:

```
<div class="example-container mat-elevation-z8">
                                        <mat-table #table [dataSource]="datasourcesO" matSort class="mat-elevation-z8">
                                            <ng-container matColumnDef="nRequest">
                                                <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> N° Solicitud
                                                </mat-header-cell>
                                                <mat-cell
                                                    *matCellDef="let i = index, let element">S{{element.headerId}}</mat-cell>
                                            </ng-container>
                                            <ng-container matColumnDef="RecLoc">
                                                <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> RecLoc
                                                </mat-header-cell>
                                                <mat-cell
                                                    *matCellDef="let i = index, let element">{{element.recLoc}}</mat-cell>
                                            </ng-container>
                                            <ng-container matColumnDef="owner">
                                                <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Dueño
                                                </mat-header-cell>
                                                <mat-cell
                                                    *matCellDef="let i = index, let element">{{element.ownerid}}</mat-cell>
                                            </ng-container>
                                            <ng-container matColumnDef="NumeroV">
                                                <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Numero de vuelo
                                                </mat-header-cell>
                                                <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.flight}}</mat-cell>
                                            </ng-container>
                                            <ng-container matColumnDef="Ruta">
                                                <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Ruta
                                                </mat-header-cell>
                                                <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.cypr}}</mat-cell>
                                            </ng-container>
                                            <ng-container matColumnDef="FechaSal">
                                                <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Fecha de salida
                                                </mat-header-cell>
                                                <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.flightdate |
                                                    date:'dd/MM/yy'}}</mat-cell>
                                            </ng-container>
                                            <ng-container matColumnDef="Asie">
                                                <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Asientos
                                                </mat-header-cell>
                                                <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.usldseats}}</mat-cell>
                                            </ng-container>
                                            <ng-container matColumnDef="Edit">
                                                <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Editar Nego
                                                </mat-header-cell>
                                                <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element; let row">
                                                    <a *ngIf="!element.lookButtons" mat-stroked-button
                                                        (click)="editDetail(row)">
                                                        <mat-icon>edit</mat-icon>
                                                    </a>

                                                    <a *ngIf="element.lookButtons" mat-stroked-button
                                                        [disabled]="element.lookButtons">
                                                        <mat-icon>edit</mat-icon>
                                                    </a>
                                                </mat-cell>
                                            </ng-container>
                                            <ng-container matColumnDef="Acc">
                                                <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Cambiar Nego
                                                </mat-header-cell>
                                                <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element; let row">
                                                    <mat-card>
                                                        <mat-icon >sync_alt</mat-icon>
                                                    </mat-card>
                                                </mat-cell>
                                            </ng-container>
                                            <ng-container matColumnDef="Disponibilidad">
                                                <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Cancelar Nego
                                                </mat-header-cell>
                                                <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element; let row">
                                                    <mat-card>
                                                        <mat-icon >close</mat-icon>
                                                    </mat-card>
                                                </mat-cell>
                                            </ng-container>
                                            <ng-container matColumnDef="Estado">
                                                <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Estado
                                                </mat-header-cell>
                                                <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
                                                    <mat-card *ngIf="element.state === 1">

                                                    </mat-card>
                                                    <mat-card *ngIf="element.state === 5"
                                                        style="background-color: #CCCBCB;">

                                                    </mat-card>
                                                    <mat-card *ngIf="element.state === 6"
                                                        style="background-color: #A600CF;">

                                                    </mat-card>
                                                    <mat-card *ngIf="element.state === 7"
                                                        style="background-color: #14D1FF;">

                                                    </mat-card>
                                                    <mat-card *ngIf="element.state === 8"
                                                        style="background-color: #6BCF00;">

                                                    </mat-card>
                                                    <mat-card *ngIf="element.state === 9"
                                                        style="background-color: #F63913;">

                                                    </mat-card>
                                                    <mat-card *ngIf="element.state === 11"
                                                        style="background-color: #CCCBCB;">

                                                    </mat-card>
                                                    <mat-card *ngIf="element.state === 13"
                                                        style="background-color: #FFD414;">

                                                    </mat-card>

                                                </mat-cell>
                                            </ng-container>
                                            <ng-container matColumnDef="Msj">
                                                <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Mensaje del estado
                                                </mat-header-cell>
                                                <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.a1status}}</mat-cell>
                                            </ng-container>
                                            <ng-container matColumnDef="Comment">
                                                <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Comment
                                                </mat-header-cell>
                                                <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.comment}}</mat-cell>
                                            </ng-container>

                                            <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumnNew"></mat-header-row>
                                            <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumnNew;"></mat-row>
                                        </mat-table>

                                        <mat-paginator #paginatorDisponibles="matPaginator"
                                            [pageSize]="10"></mat-paginator>
                                    </div>
```

Y mi componente :

```
export class CreadosComponent implements OnInit {
 @ViewChild('table', { static: true }) table: MatTable<any>;
  @ViewChild(MatSort, { static: true }) sort: MatSort;

displayedColumnNew: string[] = ['nRequest', 'RecLoc', 'owner', 'NumeroV', 'Ruta', 'FechaSal', 'Asie', 'Editar', 'Acc', 'Disp', 'Estado', 'Msj', 'Comment'];
}
```

Solo deseo que se pueda organizar mis columnas de forma asc/desc por fecha

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Y el problema cual es?

Comment: revisa este link https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples#table-overview